# iOS - React Native - Unable to install cocoa-pods while upgrading react-native 0.69.3

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cocoapods, hybrid-mobile-app

```
suresh ios % pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
RNFBAnalytics: Using default Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use analytics without ad ids.
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`

[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-Codegen (= 0.69.3)` depended upon by `React-RCTSettings`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

iOS - React Native - Unable to install cocoa-pods  while upgrading react-native 0.69.3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solutions mentioned in the error log?

```
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Especially the `pod repo update` fixes the problem for me most of the time.